# Passing function and function argument in .on('click') event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on the button it will say `Bruce Wayne is Batman`. In the last jQuery line, for the 'click' function, if I pass the parameter 'guy', the jQuery wont run, but if I don't pass in a parameter I get `undefined`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
$("div").on('click', 'button', click(guy));
```

The jsFiddle link, HTML and JS are below.

https://jsfiddle.net/wrj5w1Lk/

```
<div>
    <button>
        Click Me! Click Me!
    </button>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Person = function(first, last, secret) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    var guy = new Person("Bruce", "Wayne", "Batman");
    var click = function(person) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('p').text(person.first + " " + person.last + " is " + person.secret);
    };

    $("div").on('click', 'button', click(guy));
});
```

Comment: Please [user the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+pass+argument+event+handler) before you ask a new question.

Comment: will do. got a little too excited and the thought of searching the forum didn't cross my mind.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues, firstly you need to wrap the call to `click()` in an anonymous function. Secondly you need to pass the reference of the current `button` element to your `click()` function. Try this:

```
var click = function($element, person) {
    $element.closest('div').find('p').text(person.first + " " + person.last + " is " + person.secret);
};

$("div").on('click', 'button', function() {
    click($(this), guy);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wrj5w1Lk/1/)

Comment: `guy` isn't a string, it is defined in the javascript.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen you're right, my mistake. Answer updated.

Comment: Your answer was posted first, so I've removed mine.

Comment: If you use the optional `[data]` parameter of the `.on()` function, you can avoid making the second function call altogether. Either way, it still works. +1 :)

Comment: thanks for the inputs. i've literally have not gone through 'event' and '$element' yet... so im definitely going to read up on those later today.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that `$element` is just a variable name I defined, there's nothing special about it. The prepended `$` is just to show that the variable holds a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is how to pass custom data to the event handler using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data). The link references the optional `[ data ]` object of the `.on()` function. This allows you to pass custom data outside of the normal `event` data to your event handler for further processing. An example is shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Person = function(first, last, secret) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    var guy = new Person("Bruce", "Wayne", "Batman");
    var click = function(event) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('p').text(event.data.first + " " + event.data.last + " is " + event.data.secret);
    };

    $("div").on('click', 'button', guy, click);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button>
        Click Me! Click Me!
    </button>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

I've edited your snippet from your question to use this method of passing data. Your custom object is passed in the `event.data` object of the callback. By accessing, `event.data.[first,last,secret]` you can reference the properties of the `Person(...)` object from within your callback.

Comment: thank you!.. i haven't gone over "event" yet, so that's completely new to me. but i'm going to read up more on it. thanks so much.

Comment: Question, is event just a regular paremeter or a special javascript/jquery syntax? And many thanks in advance